# Swift 動画再生　UIをカスタマイズ

Tags: ios, swift

Swiftで動画再生アプリを開発しております。
・動画再生時の「再生ボタン」を自作のボタンにする。
・再生前の静止画を、動画の中から選択して指定する。
（現在は動画が始まる一番最初の静止画がセットされています。）

上記のようなことを実現するためにどうすればいいか教えて下さい。
また調べるときはApple公式のlibraryのどこを見ればいいのでしょうか。
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code

Githubでサンプルコードなど参考にと考えましたが、探し方がよくわかりません。

お手数ですが、アドバイスお願いします。

現在のソースコード
「AVPlayerViewControllerクラス」でデフォルトのUIになっています。

playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls =true

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/20333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVPlayerLayerを持つUIViewをViewControllerに持たせて、それをカスタマイズする形になると思います。
下記に詳しく記述があります。

AVFoundationプログラミングガイド
https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/AVFoundationPG.pdf

再生ボタンのアイコンや位置だけカスタマイズするということは残念ながらできなくて、文字通りすべてのパーツとアクション、アニメーションを自分で作りこむことになるかと思います。

Cocoa/CocoaTouch全般に共通する調べ方として、最初にまず〜〜プログラミングガイドを読む、次にApple公式のサンプルコードを検索して動かしてみる、ということをオススメします。まずは原典にあたるのが一番です。

下記でAVFoundationをキーワードに検索したところ、サンプルコード28件ヒットしました。ご参考まで。
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code

Comment: ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます!!
大変参考になりました。まずは公式を参考に実際にやってみます！

Answer (score 1):

AVPlayerViewControllerクラスが行っていることをアプリで行えば実現出来ます。
動画の再生制御と表示に必要なクラスは次の2つです。

- AVPlayer
- AVPlayerLayer

上記の2つのクラスを中心に調べれば良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！調べてみます。